# How to enable zoom for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, pinchzoom

I am confused. I have a `UICollectionView`. I have my own `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass (iow, I am not using the Flow thing). `UICollectionView` instance is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. It adds multiple subviews. But questions like [Properly zooming a UIScrollView that contains many subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835941/properly-zooming-a-uiscrollview-that-contains-many-subviews) seem to say that scrollable views should just have one subview to "scroll the whole view". Seems kind of an inconsistent marriage to me. I mean why does Apple give me a framework for making a multiple child view, and then stick them all in scroll view, which isn't supposed to work well?

So I'm curious how I should go about making my whole `UICollectionView` (it's in a `UICollectionViewController` subclass) zoomable. Do I need to implement various delegate methods and invalidate/manipulate the layout object, deriving the layouts based on some property I keep in my layout? Or is there some other mechanism?

Aside, why can't it just manipulate the `zoomScale` property and do it automagically for me? Or am I missing some subtlety here?

Comment: Same problem here. The documentation is not very clear on this at all.  Other SO questions include http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667398/is-it-possible-to-zoom-uicollectionview-as-a-unit.

Did you stumble upon a solution at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure whether I got your question in correct way or not, but I think you might want to check these links:-

1.  [zoom entire UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406254/zoom-entire-uicollectionview) - It also has a link to [Sample code for UICollectionView](https://github.com/CanTheAlmighty/SamplePinchGesture). You might be interested in checking it.

2. [Adding pinch zoom to a UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895469/adding-pinch-zoom-to-a-uicollectionview).
3. [Make UICollectionView zoomable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485617/make-uicollectionview-zoomable)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the iOS 7 Photos application type of pinching + transition, maybe take a look at this question here: [UICollectionView interactive layout transition using iOS 7 APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008307/uicollectionview-interactive-layout-transition-using-ios-7-apis)

Comment: I don't really think that's relevant to the question at all. However, that is a really interesting link about interactive layouts!