# how to implement a zoom in/out animation for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I got a UICollectionView with several cells on the screen.

I want to add one animation that can zoom out/in the cell;

The logic behind is when clicking the cell, it will invoke `[self.navigationController pushViewController:_chartViewController animated:NO];`

I am not clear how to zoom in/out the new `_chartViewController`

Looking for the APIs and some key takeaways for doing it. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a Custom Segue Animation. In your example you click a cell and it zooms to another view controller.

You can find a good example here that uses a tableview instead of a collection view: 
https://github.com/visnup/tableview-open

This code employs a tableview - when a cell is clicked it "zooms" to the respective view controller that is associated with that cell.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look and come back later

Answer (score 2):

Actually, what I am looking for is [here, on GitHub](https://github.com/objcio/issue5-view-controller-transitions). Also, check out [objc.io Issue 5](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following lines in to the viewDidLoad method of my UICollectionViewController:

```
[collectionView setMinimumZoomScale: 0.25];
[collectionView setMaximumZoomScale: 4];
```

1. zoom entire UICollectionView - It also has a link to Sample code for UICollectionView. You might be interested in checking it.
2. Adding pinch zoom to a UICollectionView.
3. Make UICollectionView zoomable? [Link](https://github.com/CanTheAlmighty/SamplePinchGesture)

or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22348713/4286978).